# Navigation Bar to Stay on top

Tags: html, css, navigation

I created a nice navigation bar and I want to stay on the top of the page even if the user is scrolling. I've created a separate PHP file for the header named *header.php* and included it on the main page.

CSS for headermenu

```
.headerMenu {
background-image: url(../img/background_white.png);
height: 56px;
border-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

It worked good though but it won't stay on the top when the user scrolls, so I decided to put some additional codes:

```
.headerMenu {
background-image: url(../img/background_white.png);
height: 56px;
border-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
width: 100%;

position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
```

After putting those two codes my navigation bar won't display on the page. 
I tried asking some people on the net and they all come up with the `position:fixed; top:0;` code. Why it's not working?

HTML

```
<div class = "headerMenu">
    <div id = "menu">
     <a href = "home.php" />What's New</a>
     <a href = "home.php" /><?php echo $firstname; ?></a>                           
     <a href = "signout_com.php" />Sign Out</a>                                             
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your html code please?

Comment: have you given 'position:relative' to <body>?

Comment: Ow my bad.. ok working on it..

Comment: You need to remove the self-closing `/` character from your `<a>` tags. You can't self-close an HTML tag and then add a closing tag after it, that is invalid.

Comment: @pratiknagariya Yeah and still nav bar dont appear.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks man. It works either way though but I followed your advice.

Comment: Yep: http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/pzkds/ (working fiddle) Your CSS is fine, just make sure you add `margin-top` to your content, and it will display below your fixed header.

Comment: It's still not working on me... does it affect external php's? I mean the header is created named 'header.php' and is linked on my 'home.php' page via include("header.php"); .

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
.headerMenu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    background-image:url(../img/background_white.png);
    height:56px;
}
```

Remove the padding, then remove the self closing tag for your anchors :)

Also make sure you are putting content underneath it :) and then add 56px margin to the top of the content element.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong in css but in html:

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/xpgzP/99/

HTML:

```
<div class="headerMenu">
        <div id="menu"> <a href="home.php">What's New</a>
     <a href="home.php">Name</a>  <a href="signout_com.php">Sign Out</a> <!--Incorrect closing tags removed-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>content
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
```